# Will I recieve a shock if I charged a capacitor, then I touch the 2 poles in same time?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, charge

What happens if I charged a capacitor, then I touch the 2 poles in same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the charge in the capacitor is large enough, you'll get a nice little shock:-), as the capacitor will discharge through you. I remember grabbing a rectifying valve disconnected from the mains a long time ago - that was not pretty (apparently, it contained a capacitor). I was "clever" enough to grab it again:-)

Comment: I've had the misfortune of doing that with a large capacitor of the sort used in power supplies back in the vacuum tube (valve) days.  It not only caused a small burn, but knocked me over.

Comment: *"If the charge in the capacitor is large enough"* --- Sounds like voltage wouldn't matter.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch : There is a well-known relationship between charge  and voltage for a certain capacitance, so I don't quite get your comment.

Comment: @akhmeteli Sure. But as long as the voltage is low, you won't get a "nice little shock", even if the "charge in the capacitor is large enough" -- whatever that even means.  What really matters for the shock is the voltage, as long as the charge is not too small.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: on the other hand, the shock will not be significant if the charge is small, even if the voltage is high, so what's the point?

Comment: I'm not so sure about that.  In the end it's about the current flowing through the body, but for how long does it have to flow? Certainly not seconds.  I'd say for the very least you should state that it's about voltage and charge.  But I'd still say that voltage is more important: As long as the voltage is large, at least for a very short time a large current will flow through the body, which will give you *some* shock.  On the other hand, for a voltage of, say, 12V, you won't experience any shock regardless of the charge.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch : " In fact, many people do not feel a shock from a static electricity discharge less than about 2,000-4,000V." (http://www.electrostatics.net/articles/static_shocks.htm). And again. there is a well-known relationship between charge, voltage, and capacitance, so why should I necessarily "state that it's about voltage and charge"? Sounds like an arbitrary demand.

Comment: Ok, again: What is a "large enough" charge?  For voltage, this seems more clear: a few thousand volts is enough, even for very small charge.  I do not agree that "charge" and "voltage" are interchangeable here, unless you fix the capacity beforehand (which is not being said anywhere -- and even if: the question is still what is the relevant figure, given no other prior knowledge: voltage or charge).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch : OK, let us agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced touching two capacitors together, when i was a child in the 1960s.

My older brother was studying Electronics at a Catholic Technical HS. I picked up capacitors from his work area and touched them together out if curiosity.  The resulting shock was huge. My arms flung apart, throwing the capacitors hard and I was knocked to the floor. The shock was enormous. I was uninjured.  I told my older brother that I touched two capacitors together. He scolded me, saying they were dangerous. Later he asked me what happened when I touched them together.